# How to update data in Parse IOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am facing an issue when trying to update data in Parse.
Here is my code that i am using.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GameScore"];

[query whereKey:@"name" equalTo:@"Username"];

[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *item, NSError *error)
{
   if (!error)
   {
       [item setObject:@500 forKey:"Score"];

   }


   [item saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *itemError)
   {

       if (!error)
       {
          NSLog(@"Score is updated");

       }
       else
       {
         NSLog(@"Error in updating: %@",error.description);

       }
   }];
 }
 else
 {
    NSLog(@"Error in getting Score: %@",error.description);

 }
}];
```

This code works only when i create a new PFObject and then try to update it.
But,when i exit my app and then try to update the score again,i am unable to update the data.It throws this error..

```
Error in getting Score: Error Domain=Parse Code=101 "No results matched the query." UserInfo={error=No results matched the query., NSLocalizedDescription=No results matched the query., code=101}
```

It works again,if i create a new PFObject.
Please help,i am new to Parse and am still try to understand it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock instead of getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock as the latter can only be used if there's at least 1 object.

[Reference - Parse Questions](https://www.parse.com/questions/ios-pfquery-getfirstobjectinbackgroundwithblock-error-when-no-results)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the PFQuery's `count` method. If the count is >= 1, use `getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock`, otherwise display a message / handle that case however you'd like.

Other options include storing the objectId of the GameScore object associated with a player on their user object, creating an object without data using the objectId, then fetching it. Or simply use a pointer, but that can do weird things when saving / querying / fetching.